# Implementing bouncing markers in an embedded google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, jquery-gmap3

I'm working on getting a bouncing marker into Google maps embedded on my page.

Here's the code right now:

```
$("#venue-map").gmap3({
 map:{
    options:{
     center:[28.500169, 77.161950],
     zoom:13,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
     mapTypeControl: false,
     navigationControl: true,
     scrollwheel: false,
     streetViewControl: false
    }
  },
   marker:{
   latLng:[28.500169, 77.161950],
   animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
   }




});
```

I don't seem to be able to get the bouncing cursor up and running correctly. any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I haven't used gmap3 - does the above code add a non-bouncing marker at the correct position?

Comment: Yes it does. But no worries, Dr.Molle below has got an answer that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options derived from the genuine `google.maps.Marker` you must pass to the options-member:

```
   marker:{
    latLng   :[28.500169, 77.161950],
    options  :{animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE}
   }
```